# Information separating from mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I'm making program for teachers with Java and mysql , so I've many tables in mysql such as students table which contains student name and number and ID .. etc , also another table that called groups , It contains group name , place and students .. etc.
So , the problem is , in Groups table I'll add IDs of students in one row just like the image bellow beside the name of group , how can I take this IDs from mysql in this form and separate them automatically in program by java to search in the students table about the information of them .

image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFQ6t.jpg

```
  try {
    Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
    Connection con = (Connection)   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teacherassistant?allowMultiQueries=true","root","1234");
    Statement st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
    String query = "select * from Groups;";
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

    while(rs.next()){
    String name = rs.getString("Name");
    String StudentIDs= rs.getString("Students");
    String Center = rs.getString("Center");

    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Error");
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make a program? I'd try with a more specific question.

Comment: It's not a shame that I don't now this ! maybe it's easy for you but I really need to know how to separate the info to use them again :3

Comment: Please add your current code into the question by editing... then we can help you better!

Comment: Please, take the good point of the critic. Try with a more specific question, not asking for a while program. Try by yourself and once you stuck with something search for info and, if any doubt , ask here.

Comment: You shouldn't store the group information like this. You should have three tables - students, groups, and student-to-group. That's the classical way of representing a many to many relationship in a relational database. Research this topic, as well as database normalization, design your database properly, and the problem will solve itself.

Comment: Okay thank you guys :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do that.

The relationship between groups and students is clearly a many-to-many relationship. Instead make a new table that contains this relationship. Something like;

```
STUDENT_GROUP_REL
------------------
(student_id, group_id)
```

There is a related question and [a very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3397411/22186) about m:n relations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397349/meaning-of-nm-and-1n-in-database-design)