# (DOCTRINE) mappedBy and inversedBy and targetEntity annotations

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

What values goes inside this `inversedBy` annotation as well as the `mappedBy` annotation? **Also what is targetEntity and referencedColumnName?**

Here is an example of my `comment entity`. As you can see, in my tutorials it says to write the string `comments` inside the `inversedBy` attribute and `\Application\Entity\Post` inside the `targetREntity` attribute.

```
/**
 * This class represents a comment related to a blog post.
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="comment")
 */
class Comment
{

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Application\Entity\Post", inversedBy="comments")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  protected $post;
}
```

For this one, it says `comments`. **What exactly is this comments string referring to?** 
 **I dont know what comments means. Is this a mapping to a table, or the ORM name of the class at the top, or something else.**

Also,

Here is an example of where `mappedBy` is used:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="post")
*/
class Post 
{
  // Post status constants.
  const STATUS_DRAFT       = 1; // Draft.
  const STATUS_PUBLISHED   = 2; // Published.

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Application\Entity\Comment", mappedBy="post")   
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="post_id")
   */
  protected $comments;
```

I started reading about `owning sides and inverse sides` [click here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#) but it was extremely difficult to understand.

Any details on anything here would be great.

**Any help would be great.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not doctrine expect but I used to work with it for some time so I'll try to explain what I know so far.

**InversedBy** refers to `$comments` property (field) in `Post` entity and vice versa.

> The inverse side has to use the mappedBy attribute of the OneToOne,
>   OneToMany, or ManyToMany mapping declaration. The mappedBy attribute
>   contains the name of the association-field on the owning side.
>
> The owning side has to use the inversedBy attribute of the OneToOne,
>   ManyToOne, or ManyToMany mapping declaration. The inversedBy attribute
>   contains the name of the association-field on the inverse-side.

When you use `@ORM\ManyToOne` annotation you are creating [n:1 relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397349/meaning-of-nm-and-1n-in-database-design). There are three [types of mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#):

- **bidirectional** - `Post` with access to `Comment` and **vice versa**
- **unidirectional** - `Post` with `$comments` field full of  `Comment` entities but you won't have ability to access `Post` from `Comment`, because it is not mapped back
- **self-referencing** - `Category` with with **self-reference** to parent `Category` which is entity of same type

**TargetEntity** tells to which entity you are creating relationship. Imagine foreign key. When you create foreign key you need to specify referencing table.

**ReferencedColumnName** tells to which column foreign key should be created.

Doctrine is not magic. It is just Object Relation Mapping. Think about it like when you used SQL to create relations. A lot of things are almost same.