# What is the best way to retrieve multiple data based on given ID's in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

```
Table1: Places (a place can have multiple contacts)
Columns: place_id, place_name, ...

Table2: Contacts (a contact can visit multiple places)
Columns: contact_id, contact_name, ...

Table3: PlacesContacts
Columns: id, place_id, contact_id
```

Then I want to get all users from a specific place then I can do something like:

```
select * from PlacesContacts where place_id = 3
```

I will get all `contact_id's` I need but also I want to get all the `contact_id's` data from `Contacts` table.

What is the best possible way to achieve this?

Comment: Sit down with any basic introductory book or tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple INNER JOIN statement:

```
SELECT PlacesContacts.*, Contacts.* 
FROM PlacesContacts 
INNER JOIN Contacts 
ON PlacesContacts.contact_id = Contacts.contact_id
WHERE PlacesContacts.place_id = 3;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use a join:

```
SELECT pc.*, c.*
FROM PlacesContacts pc
INNER JOIN Contacts c
    ON pc.contact_id = c.contact_id
WHERE pc.place_id = 3;
```

Comment: If I have multiple contact_id's with that place_id, will I get the data of each contact_id?

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting the idea now.

Answer (score 1):

your contact_id from PlaceContacts is from the Contacts table, isn't it?
then you can join those 2 table

```
select PlacesContacts.*,Contacts.* from PlacesContacts
inner join Contacts on Contacts.contact_id=PlacesContacts.contact_id
 where place_id = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the relation between Tables - Places and Contacts is m:n. (Check #1 if you have no idea what is a m to n relationship)
Then Tim Biegeleisen's answer will help you.

Else if it is a 1:n relationship. Maybe you should add place_id into the Contacts table and remove the PlacesContacts.

## 1 - [Meaning of "n:m" and "1:n" in database design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397349/meaning-of-nm-and-1n-in-database-design?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)